# C# Android default icon after changing

Tags: c#, android, icons, android-manifest

I tried to change the icon of my app today, but even after I changed it in my project's properties, in MainActivity.cs and in AndroidManifest.xml after building and running the aplication it showed me the default android icon.

I even tried replacing the original ico.png with my icon but that didn't work either.

So my question is how can I successfully change my applications icon?

It should be a simple thing to do in my opinion,
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Change the ic_launcher drawable in the mipmap directory!
Rebuild the app and install it again (maybe you need first to deinstall the app)

Comment: How do i find the mipmap directory?

Comment: It is located here:
`YourProjectFolder\app\src\main\res` To create all mipmap ic_launcher sizes, you can use Android Asset Studio (https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-launcher.html)